# Inspect marshalled Pojo with a Processor with Camel and Bindy

Tags: java, apache-camel, pojo, bindy

I have a flat file, in which each line needs to be captured and unmarshalled into a `POJO`. I am using `Camel` and `Bindy` and utilizing the `Splitter EIP`. For some reason i am not able to inspect the `POJO` (using a `Processor`) after the unmarshalling completed. Any suggestions?

I am trying to debug the `Exchange` inside the `Process` right after both `Bindy` conversions below. The code never gets invoked (breakpoint never reaches)

Here is my code:

```
from("file://inbox")
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple("${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.${file:ext}")) 
    .wireTap("file://ORIGINAL_BACKUP")
    .process(converterProcessor)
    .split(body(String.class).tokenize(System.lineSeparator()))
    .choice()       
    .when(new Predicate() {

        public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
            if(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString().startsWith("HEADER1")) return true;
            return false;
        }
    })      
    .unmarshal()
    .bindy(BindyType.Fixed, MessageHeaderGroup_HEADER1.class).process(new Processor() {

        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Object: "+ exchange.getIn().getBody());

        }
    }).to("direct:mhg")

    .when(new Predicate() {

        public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
            if(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString().startsWith("HEADER2")) return true;
            return false;
        }
    })
    .unmarshal()
    .bindy(BindyType.Fixed, TransactionHeaderGroup_HEADER2.class).process(new Processor() {

        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Object: "+ exchange.getIn().getBody());

        }
    }).to("direct:trg")
    .otherwise().to("file://outbox");
```

I am fairly new to `Camel`. I have tried to end the `choice()` using `endChoice()` but to no avail. If i use a `Filter EIP` (to only use one possible `Bindy` conversion) i can inspect the `Exchange` in the `Process` step. But if i switch to a `choice()` with `Predicate` i am not able to. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `wireTap`? This could be your Problem. See the documentation --> [wire-tap](http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html).

> If you Wire Tap a stream message body then you should consider enabling Stream caching to ensure the message body can be read at each endpoint. See more details at Stream caching.

Please set a BreakPoint in your `converterProcessor` and look inside the exchange.

If you only want to move the file you can make a simple `.to("file://ORIGINAL_BACKUP")` and then go on. Another way:

```
from("file://inbox?move=ORIGINAL_BACKUP/${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.${file:ext}")
```

Comment: I use Wire Tap to save a copy of my original flat file. It is not a necessity on my part to have it. I have tested without it as well. I came to find out that the problem was an exception being thrown while Bindy was unmarshalling the file to a POJO. Since i am fairly new to Camel, i was confused by the fact that i did not see the exception on my console in Eclipse. Do you know of a good way to show errors/exception in your route as it is being traversed? I am yet to research the Exception Handling facilities in Camel, but need some debugging tips before i get there. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, to answer my question above to those interested - here is a similar question i stumbled upon that should get me started on a verbose exception handling during route traversal in Camel - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487115/apache-camel-bindy-how-to-log-or-debug?rq=1